# how to place ".py" file into the search path of your python installation

Tags: python

I have two files say  `Geometry.py` and `PeptideBuilder.py` for their installation  They need to be placed into the search path of my python installation on ubuntu linux machine.

how can I know  the search path of my python installation and how can I place them .

Comment: Do you know the path to these two files?

Comment: actually i was trying to install two different  modules for first module i used  "export PYTHONPATH=/home/andersx/dev/fragbuilder:$PYTHONPATH" command which is not working and for second module i need to place these two file within the python search path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use this for a project, update python path in your main script:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '.path/to/folder/with/scripts')
```

If you need them for any instance of python, you should have sudo rights and put them in site-packages(check first PYTHONPATH for your py version):

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

Usual, the standard module path is like „/usr/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages”.
(that's standard in my Arch, but may be different on Ubuntu, that's way is better to check)

EDIT: if scripts are strictly related to your project, just puthem on same level with script that import's them, but I think you allready do that.

Comment: after placing both the file in "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages" now i am able to import both the modules thanks